# Keyerror with 2d dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to step through a csv and assign date and time values to their own point in a 2d dictionary.This would be in a form such that an instance of:

'11/02/16' and '23:24' in their respective columns in a row would add '1' to the value in the position marked by 'X' in the dictionary 'Dates{11/01/16{23:X}}'.

Unfortunately I get a KeyError for the following code.

```
import csv
import sys
from sys import argv
from collections import defaultdict
script, ReadFile = argv

f = open(ReadFile,'r')
l = f.readlines()
f.close()

file_list = [row.replace('\n','').split(',') for row in l]
header = file_list[0]

Total = 0 
Dates = defaultdict(dict)
print Dates

index_variable = header.index('Time')
index_variable2 = header.index('# Timestamp')

for row in file_list[1:]:
    t = row[index_variable][:2]
    d = row[index_variable2][:10]
    if row[index_variable2][:10] in Dates:
        Dates[d][t] = 1
        Total += 1
        print "true"
    else:
        Dates[d] = {}
        Dates[d][t] = 1
        Total =+ 1
        print "false"

 print Dates
```

If I replace the local variable 't' with "'Test'" the code works, but obviously the results are not what I'm after.

Thanks in advance!

Update: If I replace 'd' with 'Test' and keep 't' as it is, the program works completely fine. It's only when the Dictionary is specifically called as 'Dates[d][t]' that the program returns a KeyError.

Update 2: I've updated the code above to show my work. Currently the script will work /as long as no numbers are added/.

```
Dates[d][t] = 1 #If I change this...
Dates[d][t] += 1 #To this...
```

A KeyError occurs.

Update 3:

I changed a portion of my code...

```
for row in file_list[1:]:
    t = row[index_variable][:2]
    d = row[index_variable2][:10]
    if d in Dates and t in Dates[d]:
        Dates[d][t] += 1
        print "true"
    else:
        Dates[d][t] = 1
        print "false"
```

And now the script works perfectly fine. I suppose that this means the KeyError was because I was not being specific enough (???).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what we see above is just bad formatting of the if by the machine...

I think the problem is in the else:

Dates is a dict with various keys.

The d are the first 10 characters of the 'Date' field in your input

You are wanting to count how many times the minutes got hit on a specific Date.

Dates[d] then is a dictionary whose keys are days.

t is supposed to be a dictionary of minutes that got hit on the specific day

You haven't told python that Dates[d] is a dictionary too. 
But you've made a reference to Dates[d][t].  This implies that Dates[d] already exists and it has something that is subscriptable in it.

I tried this on my system

```
import csv
import sys
from sys import argv
from collections import defaultdict
#script, ReadFile = argv

#f = open(ReadFile,'r')
#l = f.readlines()
#f.close()

#file_list = [row.replace('\n','').split(',') for row in l]
#header = file_list[0]
file_list = [['Date','Time','Otherstuff'],
             ['2016-02-01','23:12:00','Sillyme1'],
             ['2016-02-01','23:12:04','Sillyme2'],
             ['2016-02-02','22:10:00','Sillyme3']]
header = file_list[0]

Dates = defaultdict(dict)
print(Dates)

index_variable = header.index('Time')
index_variable2 = header.index('Date')

for row in file_list[1:]:
    t = row[index_variable][:2]
    d = row[index_variable2][:10]
    if d in Dates.keys():
        Dates[d][t] +=1
        print("true")
    else:
        Dates[d] = {} #Now Dates[d] contains a dictionary
        Dates[d][t] = 1 ##Now we put the first counter in the Dates[d] dictionary with key t.

print(Dates)
```

Return was:

defaultdict(, {})

true

defaultdict(, {'2016-02-01': {'23': 2}, '2016-02-02': {'22': 1}})

Comment: Having tried the code you enclosed, it returned the same output in the form that would be correct for what I'm trying to do.  I assume this means that it's the structure of the csv that is causing some error with '[t]'.

Comment: I've narrowed down the cause of the error to something involving the addition in the code. I can assign the values in the dictionary, but if I try to add to them then the script throws out a KeyError.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't comment above.  Glad you got it.  When you do "if d in Dates" you are checking whether d is a key in Dates the and then follows "t in Dates[d]" checks whether t is a key in the Dates[d] dictionary.  Remember, we were working with a dictionary of dictionaries.